# ReportServerCentralAdmin Missing Feature

Tags: sharepoint-server, reporting-services

I have SharePoint 2013 On-Prem with a single wfe, a single app server and a dedicated SSRS application Server running SSRS in integrated mode. The DB running SSRS is SQLServer2016 SP2. This server was upgraded and the rsAddin was upgraded on the WFE and the App Server (as it also runs web app so technically this is a wfe).

PSConfig was run after the install of rsAddin but central administration shows  missing feature: Name = [Report Server Central Administration Feature], Id = [5f2e3537-91b5-4341-86ff-90c6a2f99aae] …

The rsAddin is for 2016 and  is version 13.2.5201.2

Everything is working fine in regards to Central Admin Manage Services and the delivery of reports. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: This would lead me to think that the previous version of rsAddin is still being referenced in one or more of your content databases.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin on the app server, where central admin is, reran the psconfig script and reanalyzed but it is still showing as missing.

Answer (score 0):

You could download and install the SQL server 2016 reporting service add-in for SharePoint 2013 from the link below.

[Microsoft® SQL Server® 2016 Reporting Services Add-in for Microsoft SharePoint®.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52682)

If you have installed it, try to uninstall and re-install it and compare the results.

Comment: To complicate matters:
The SQL Server 2016 we are using is SP2-CU2-GDR KB3194721 (11.0.6248.0)
The hyperlink points to a different version.
The RSSHAREPOINT.msi that I used was pulled from the SP2 iso used in the upgrade.
Looking at the property details I see:
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 RS Addin for SharePoint
Revision Number: {A576B533-D472-4DA5-80CC-BC7DCB1CE18C}

Comment: Last night I uninstalled the rsaddin from the app server and reinstalled it. I ran psconfig afterwards.   The Programs and Features still reports a Missing Dependency. The version I used is the one you linked to. SQL Server is 2016 SP4 GDR. We need to put the June 2019 CU on the farm and I am concerned that this will prevent the farm from successfully receiving the CU.